# Pandas style code not work in conda environment on spyder, packages issue?

Tags: python, pandas, package, anaconda, pandas-styles

I am trying to run this example bit of code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(24)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.linspace(1, 10, 10)})
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('BCDE'))],
               axis=1)
df.iloc[0, 2] = np.nan

df.style.background_gradient(cmap='summer_r')
```

If I run it on Google Colab and it produces the expected colour coded table but when I run it on Spyder, which I have running through a Conda environment, with `pandas` and `numpy` packages installed it doesn't show any table.

Any ideas what the issue might be?

Comment: Do you look at variable explorer?

Comment: I switched to a remote server Jupyter Notebook setup in the end.